# Google YOLO sign in does not work when user has 2+ accounts

Tags: google-api, google-signin, google-identity

I am using Google YOLO ([One-tap sign-up and auto sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/)).

When there is only one user signed in a Google account in the browser **it works well**. But when I sign in 2 Google accounts - YOLO provides popup where I can choose one of them - but then happens nothing.

I load these two scripts:

- https://apis.google.com/js/api.js
- https://smartlock.google.com/client

and my code is generally like this:

```
await window.googleyolo.hint(options);
window.gapi.load('auth2', async () => {
    var googleAuth = await window.gapi.auth2.init(options);
    if (googleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) {
        var authResponse = googleAuth.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse();
        // use authResponse.id_token & authResponse.access_token to sign in
    }
});
```

The problem is that in described case the `googleAuth.isSignedIn.get()` is `false`. No information why, no error, just `false`.

I read and tried lot of stuff, SO is my last chance. thx

Comment: How did you get to register? I get an "API is out of beta and not available now" message.

Comment: @Ciprian they have whitelist, you must request access

Comment: Where did you request access?

Comment: Beta test program is currently closed. Joining was accessible from here earlier: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/